# How to fix "Target runtime doesn't support covariant types in overrides?

Tags: c#

I have Builder, let's see code:

```
public abstract class UISchemaBuilderBase
{
   protected readonly UISchemaSpecification UiSchemaSpecification;

   public UISchemaSpecification Builder() =>
      UiSchemaSpecification;

   public virtual UISchemaBuilderBase AddBoolean(
       string fieldName,
       string groupName = null)

   {
       .. some logic
    
       UiSchemaSpecification.Properties[ fieldName ] = schema;
       return this;
   }
}
```

```
public class UISchemaBuilder : UISchemaBuilderBase
{
    public UISchemaBuilder() : base(new UISchemaSpecification()) { }

    public UISchemaGroupBuilder StartGroup(string name)
    {
        UiSchemaSpecification.ParsecMetadata ??= new();
        UiSchemaSpecification.ParsecMetadata.Groups ??= new();
        UiSchemaSpecification.ParsecMetadata.Groups.Add( new(name) );

        return new UISchemaGroupBuilder(name, this, UiSchemaSpecification);
    }
}
```

```
public class UISchemaGroupBuilder : UISchemaBuilderBase
{
    private readonly string _name;
    private readonly UISchemaBuilder _schemaBuilder;

    public UISchemaGroupBuilder(
       string name,
       UISchemaBuilder schemaBuilder,
       UISchemaSpecification specification)
       : base(specification)
    {
        _name = name;
        _schemaBuilder = schemaBuilder;
    }

   public override UISchemaGroupBuilder AddBoolean(
       string fieldName,
       string fieldTitle,
       string groupName = null)
    {
        base.AddBoolean(fieldName, fieldTitle, _name);
        return this;
    }

    public UISchemaBuilder EndGroup() =>
        _schemaBuilder;
}
```

So implemented code allows to do this:

```
var builder = new UISchemaBuilder()
  .StartGroup("groupName")
    .AddBoolean()
  .EndGroup()
  .StartGroup("anotherGroupName")
    .AddBoolean()
  .EndGroup()
  .Build();
```

The problem is: I can't do the same in netstandard and I don't understand how to fix this..
I should change return type of methods in `UISchemaGroupBuilder`. For example `AddText` should return `UISchemaBuilderBase`, not `UISchemaGroupBuilder`.
But if I follow by these advices, my builder wouldn't work. I can't use `EndGroup` after `AddBoolean` for example.
Can someone help me, please?

Comment: *I can't do the same in netstandard* cannot do what? where is offended line ?

Comment: do you actually need netstandard?

Comment: I already described the issue. In net6 all methods of UISchemaGroupBuilder have UISchemaGroupBuilder return type. But when I switched to netstandard2 I got error: target runtime doesn't support covariant return types in overrides

Comment: yes, I need netstandard and I don't want to use any "hacks" [such like that](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/1d9e50cb4735df46d3de0cee5791e97295eaf588/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/RuntimeFeature.cs)

Comment: Please cut this down to a [mre] as it is much more difficult to understand what your problem is.

Comment: hm okay, I will try, give me some minutes

Comment: have you considered hiding the base logic in a protected method? eg. `public UISchemaBuilderBase AddBoolean() { ActualLogicOfAddBoolean(); return this; }; protected virtual void ActualLogicOfAddBoolean() { }` and in derived class override the protected method `ActualLogicOfAddBoolean` instead of the public method?

Comment: https://github.com/INTERNALINTERFERENCE/CovariantTest @DavidG

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vkZ4wp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [this article about C# versions from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version#defaults):

> .NET Standard 2.1 C# - 8.0
>
> .NET Standard 2.0 C# - 7.3

But [`covariant return types`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/covariant-returns) is part of C# 9, thus it is not compatible with .Net Standard.

Basically covariant return types in override methods require changes in CLR in comparison with previous language version, so it is incompatible with in .Net Framework and .Net Standard.

In OP example, `AddBool` method of group builder could be a non-virtual method, just an overloaded one which hides method in the base class hierarchy:

```
public class UISchemaGroupBuilder : UISchemaBuilderBase
{
    ...
    public new UISchemaGroupBuilder AddBoolean(
       string fieldName,
       string fieldTitle,
       string groupName = null)
    {
        base.AddBoolean(fieldName, fieldTitle, _name);
        return this;
    }
```

Comment: FWIW I would be wary of using the `new` keyword, especially in user-facing code. e.g. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/153738/what-are-some-practical-uses-of-the-new-modifier-in-c-with-respect-to-hiding

Comment: Yes, but here overloaded AddBoolean calls base class' method and that's it. So it doesn't break the contract of base method. Only difference with base method that it returns object of more specific type, which is IMO good, as it allow for more compile time checks (IMO it's much better to have a compilation error that EndGroup method is not found rather than potential runtime exception )

Answer (score 2):

Since covariant return types aren't available prior to C# 9, you can instead make use of generics. For example, a simplified version of your code, make the builder base generic and give it a constraint:

```
public abstract class UISchemaBuilderBase<TSchemaBuilder>
    where TSchemaBuilder : UISchemaBuilderBase<TSchemaBuilder>
{
    public virtual TSchemaBuilder AddBoolean()
        => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Now your derived classes must specify the generic type:

```
public class UISchemaBuilder : UISchemaBuilderBase<UISchemaBuilder>
{
    public override UISchemaBuilder AddBoolean()
        => throw new NotImplementedException();

}

public class UISchemaGroupBuilder : UISchemaBuilderBase<UISchemaGroupBuilder>
{
    public override UISchemaGroupBuilder AddBoolean()
        => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Comment: What about `EndGroup` ? let start with base `StartGroup` would return group builder ... then what should return `EndGroup` ? well it depends if `StartGroup` was called on group or on base ... **edit: On the other hand there is no such requiremnets here**